# Cant insert identity column in EF, despite never changing the value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im trying to update a table row using EntityFramework, **without changing the ID column in my code**. Why is it still telling me I can't insert an explicit value?

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tblLicenseGroups' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

MY CODE

```
//mytbl context is initialized as _gc
var mymodel=_gc.mytbl.Where(x=>x.ID.ToString()=="1").FirstorDefault();
mymodel.otherfield=22;//sets a new value
_gc.Add(mymodel);
_gc.SaveChanges();
```

EF MODEL

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int otherfield { get; set; }
```

SQL CREATE

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLicenseGroups](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ....
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblSiteParentIDs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: You're retrieving an existing record and adding it again as if it's a new record. What are you trying to do?

Comment: So you are trying to insert multiples copies with different id's. EF may intercept the requirement and prevent you doing it before it goes to the database… Why don't you use a stored procedure for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have retrieved and then modified the model with the same instance of the DbContext then you don't need to call the `Add` Method, just `.SaveChanges()`

The Update part happens automatically because EF tracks the changes that you have made to the objects from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting out an existing record and attempting to add it again.

The error your receiving is probably because you have an `identity` field in your database, having `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` in your code suggests this is true.

You may want to try something to the affect of:

```
 var mymodel=_gc.mytbl.Where(x=>x.ID.ToString()=="1").FirstorDefault();
 mymodel.ID = 0;
 _gc.Add(mymodel);
_gc.SaveChanges();
```

The code is above is intending to register the model as a new version of itself, which should add a new record to your database table that is exactly the same as the first apart from the ID

Hope this helps

Comment: I added another field to my example to show the fact that I am changing other fields, and still getting this error. Sorry for the confusion